# Pausing rsync via bash script?

Tags: bash, command-line, shell-script, rsync, cygwin

Is there a way to pause rsync via command line, if it transfers data for over X minutes?  I'm working on using it as a backup and would like it to pause every once in a while to prevent the hard disks from overheating or network throttling.  I am currently using a Windows batch file to start a Linux bash script via cygwin to do this.

Comment: @Christopher You do not need to run rsync as a daemon to use the --bwlimit switch.

Comment: Pausing a network command is tricky, you will likely run into timeouts.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get the PID of the process, you can use

> `kill –STOP`*pid*

to pause the process, and

> `kill –CONT`*pid*

to resume it. 
Check the exit status; if the `kill` command fails,
the first assumption is that the process no longer exists (because it has finished).

Comment: If you have one `rsync` instance running, you can get the PID by `ps | command grep rsync | awk '{print $1}'`. You can run your command in a while script with a `sleep` function in between.

Comment: Note however that if you pause rsync for too long, its TCP connection will eventually time out. How long you have depends on how intermediate firewalls are configured.